# Facebook mobile canvas url -> not working?

Tags: facebook-canvas

I've setup an app with Facebook canvas. I use a secure url:
https://www.renemaxhosting.nl/wielersport/
I've put the same url as the mobile url, that's used to redirect mobile users.
This always worked but stopped working since last week.

When I try to open the app on my pc it's working fine, but on smartphone i get error 'can't find given url'.

https://apps.facebook.com/knwuwielersport
secure canvas url: https://www.renemaxhosting.nl/wielersport/

[image: settings for this app]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm dealing with the same issue. Apparently Facebook temporary shut this function down due to issues with malicous Facebook Apps redirecting users to phishing sites and such. You can read more and stay updated on a solution here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/

Comment: thanks.. very bad of Facebook to do this. We are running several campaigns with apps.